# internationalization jquery SlickGrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

It's possible to internationalize the standards formatters and editors on SlickGrid? I need it on English and Spanish languages.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked the same question on Github, here is the answer:

http://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/issue/64/#comment_288695

Basically, the authors says that only slick.grid.js (and slick.model.js) is part of the SlickGrid core files, all others are "samples".

There exist some jQuery plugin to localize stuff, but you really don't need any of them... I would suggest you read how the JQuery UI DatePicker is localizing it's strings, and you can just do the same with your editors (that's what I do anyway)

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/Localization